# Visual Studio solution with multiple ASP.NET web applications

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I've got a Visual Studio 2010 solution that has multiple web applications in it. I've set one as the startup project but when I debug Visual Studio is starting up a development server for each web application in my solution. Is there anyway I can have Visual Studio only start up the development server for just the default startup project?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

At the website (or project) level, set "Always Start when Debugging" = false (the default, as shown in my screenshot, is true.)

[image: Always Start when Debugging]

Comment: +1, good one @David. I didn't knew this option existed. Probably because I never needed it but still good to know.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't looking at the properties pane but rather on the project properties. I'm surprised the option isn't also there.

Comment: Dear god, that would have saved me a few million cpu cycles.

Comment: This is stored in .user file. Is there any way of adding this in project or solution file, so I can add the change to source control?

Comment: Anyone voting the answer up, don't forget to vote up the question!