# how does VIsual Studio 2010 decide which projects to start up in a webdev instance?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, build

I have a solution with two web applications/projects. Both start up on F5 but on shift+F5 only one stops forcing me to manually close the webdav of the second one application. I don't want to create marcos to shut down the process and I don't see the properties window with the option in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186096/visual-studio-solution-with-multiple-asp-net-web-applications) I just see normal properties pages of the project.

So if I don't manually stop the webdev server and I press F5 again I get a message "Unable to start debugging" because the port is fixed on the web app which didn't stop. Note that it says "Unable to start debugging" **not** "Unable to start debugging in the web dev".

How does VS decide ok let me run this two web applications but if I have two winform apps its smart enough to start just the strat up project ? Thank you

PS: I don't believe it's in the build files, so where is it ? In the loaded environment or something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on your project in solution explorer that you dont want to start up, and in the properties window set "Always start when debugging" to false. If you don't see the properties window, press F4 or go to View -> Properties Window.  I usually set that to false for all projects and then only the project set as the startup project will start.

Comment: Mmm thanks, but I don't have this option. F4 & View -> Properties Window is the same as right click properties.

Comment: Right click -> properties takes you to a different a property page, with a bunch of different tabs on the left. You just want the property window which by default is a tab to the right below solution explorer.

Comment: Actually, I don't see the option for the web application which shutdowns properly either. Would mind to tell me what projecttypeguids in the build file are needed to see this option ?

Comment: Thanks for helping bkaid but somehow I don't see it takes me to the property pages, strange stuff. What the heck am I doing wrong here...

Comment: Post a screen shot of your window and maybe we can see the issue.  I was able to see the option when I did File -> New Website or File -> New Project -> ASP.NET MVC Web application.

Comment: Thanks for your help bkaid, I'm at home now so I have no access to the work machine to give you a screenshot but I'll try your suggestions tomorrow and hopefully something will work. Thank you so much again.