# How to stop 1 solution from starting ALL your websites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webserver, asp.net-development-serv

I am working in a solution with about 30 projects.
All projects are build for 1 specific customer(hence the same solution) but not all of them depend on each other.
We have for example a back-end API, a front-end API, 2 websites, a few services etc.

The problem i have is that everytime i start to debug 1 of those projects, visual studio boots up 9 ASP.NET development servers(1 for each website/service).

Even projects that are not being referenced or are excluded from the current build configuration are being booted up.
Does anyone know of a way to stop this from happening? My main frustration about this is the extra time it takes to boot these services up.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question has been asked before, take a look here:

[Visual Studio solution with multiple ASP.NET web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186096/visual-studio-solution-with-multiple-asp-net-web-applications)

To be complete I'll include the answer here as well.

> At the website (or project) level, set "Always Start when Debugging" =
>   false (the default, as shown in my screenshot, is true.)

[image]

Or you can also choose to setup IIS Express and use that web server instead of the Visual Studio Web Development Server.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

Comment: Tried googling and looking on stackoverflow for this question but hadn't find it, thanks for linking it ! 1 problem i have though : it seems that my referenced web api's arn't being build.