# Visual Studio 2012 automatically start web project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012.  I have created several web applications.  At one point I set the projects to automatically start when I run the startup project.  Now I would like to change that option so they do not start but I cannot find it anywhere.  I have searched the internet including SO and can't seem to find the right keywords to find the search results that would give me the answer.  It is driving me nuts!

Can someone please tell me how to tell VS 2012 not to automatically start?

Comment: In VS 2010 if you right-click the solution in Solution Explorer and select Properties, you may specify your startup projects there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably looking for this option: `Always Start when Debugging`. It is a per-project setting, see Properties window (F4). Answer taken from [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186096/visual-studio-solution-with-multiple-asp-net-web-applications).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I always forget to look at the Properties window because I am so used to doing a "right-click | Properties.

Comment: You are welcome! And thanks for pointing out it is a Properties window, not a dialog. Even though I meant that, it was not clear in my answer - now fixed.